# What is the use of the WORK parameters in LAPACK routines?

Tags: python, cython, lapack, lapacke

I am computing an eigenvalue decomposition of a symmetric matrix with `scipy.linalg.cython_lapack.syev`. From the [doc I found](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen_ga442c43fca5493590f8f26cf42fed4044.html), I need to pass an array called WORK:

> WORK is DOUBLE PRECISION array, dimension (MAX(1,LWORK))
>             On exit, if INFO = 0, WORK(1) returns the optimal LWORK.

However, I can't see what it does (can't understand what the values after execution are), nor what it's used for. What is the purpose of this parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the cython interface to `dsyev()` from scipy.linalg.cython_lapack makes sense: [numpy `eigh` wraps dsyevs](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.c.src) and [scipy `eigh` wraps dsyevr()](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/linalg/decomp.py#L241-L445). But, following the Fortran prototype of `dsyev()`, an array WORK must be provided.

The array `WORK` is required by `syev` for internal use (expect if `LWORK = -1`).

LAPACK is written in [Fortran 77](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node7.html) and this langage [does not support dynamic allocation on the heap in its standards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102753/allocatable-arrays-in-fortran-77-and-gfortran)! Dynamic allocation might have been plateform-dependent or provided by specific compiler extentions. Consequently, LAPACK is written so that the user could use whatever she/he wants: static arrays, arrays allocated on the stack or array allocated on the heap.

Indeed, hard-coding the size for the `WORK` array in the library would trigger two ackward situations. Either the array is too big, increasing the memory footprint for nothing, or the array is too small, leading to bad performance or out-of-bound errors (segmentation faults...). As a result, the memory management is left to the user of the library. Some help is provided to the user as the optimal size for the array is provided if `LWORK = -1`.

If dynamic allocation is available, the most common use of LAPACK functions is to first perform a workspace query using `LWORK = -1`, then use the return value to allocate a `WORK` array of the correct size and finally call the routine of LAPACK to get the expected result. High-end wrappers of LAPACK such as LAPACKE features function doing just that: take a look at the [source of LAPACKE for function `LAPACKE_dsyev()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d47/lapacke__dsyev_8c_source.html)! It calls twice the function `LAPACKE_dsyev_work`, which calls `LAPACK_dsyev` (wrapping `dsyev()`).

Wrappers still feature functions such as `LAPACKE_dsyev_work()`, where the arguments `work` and `lwork` are still required. The number of allocations can therefore be reduced if the routine is called multiple times on similar sizes by not deallocating `WORK` between calls, but the user must do that himself (see this [example](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapacke.html)). In addition, the [source of `ILAENV`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d8/d6d/_s_r_c_2ilaenv_8f_source.html), the function of LAPACK called to compute the optimzed size of `WORK`, features the following text:

> This version provides a set of parameters which should give good,
>     but not optimal, performance on many of the currently available
>     computers.  Users are encouraged to modify this subroutine to set
>     the tuning parameters for their particular machine using the option
>     and problem size information in the arguments.

As a result, testing sizes of WORK larger than the size returned by the workspace query could improve performances.

Indeed, lots of functions in LAPACK feature the `WORK` and `LWORK` arguments. If you search for `alloc` in folder lapack-3.7.1/SRC by `grep -r "alloc" .`
, the output only features comment lines:

```
    ./zgejsv.f:*>          Length of CWORK to confirm proper allocation of workspace.
    ./zgejsv.f:*>            In both cases, the allocated CWORK can accommodate blocked runs
    ./zgejsv.f:*>          Length of RWORK to confirm proper allocation of workspace.
    ./zgesdd.f:*       minimal amount of workspace allocated at that point in the code,
    ./zhseqr.f:*     ==== NL allocates some local workspace to help small matrices
    ./dhseqr.f:*     ==== NL allocates some local workspace to help small matrices
    ./dgesdd.f:*       minimal amount of workspace allocated at that point in the code,
    ./shseqr.f:*     ==== NL allocates some local workspace to help small matrices
    ./chseqr.f:*     ==== NL allocates some local workspace to help small matrices
    ./sgesdd.f:*       minimal amount of workspace allocated at that point in the code,
    ./sgejsv.f:*>          Length of WORK to confirm proper allocation of work space.
    ./cgejsv.f:*>          Length of CWORK to confirm proper allocation of workspace.
    ./cgejsv.f:*>            In both cases, the allocated CWORK can accommodate blocked runs
    ./cgejsv.f:*>          Length of RWORK to confirm proper allocation of workspace.
    ./dgejsv.f:*>          Length of WORK to confirm proper allocation of work space.
    ./cgesdd.f:*       minimal amount of workspace allocated at that point in the code,
```

It shows that the core of LAPACK does not handle dynamic memory allocation on the heap by commands like `allocate`, which is [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124185/i-cant-allocate-memory-for-bigger-matrices-then-200x200-lapack-visual-studio-i) for large arrays: the user must care for that himself.

Comment: Very thorough answer, merci. I was used to calling BLAS routines (linalg.cython_blas) for which no memory allocation is required, hence my "surprise".

Answer (score 3):

`syev` needs additional space during the calculation and the caller must provide this memory (`work` array).

There is a minimal amount of additional memory necessary for the calculation, however if you can afford to allocate more memory the calculation would profit from it and be faster.

The minimal size of the work array should be `(nb +2)n` where `nb` is the block size (which can be calculated via `ilaenv`).

Usually, one gives more memory: one either knows the optimal size because the structure of the matrix is known or by calling `syev` with `lwork = -1`, which would return the optimal size (in the `work` array):

```
double query;
int lwork = -1;
dsyev(..., &query, lwork);//query the work-size (error handling missing) 
lwork=(int) query; //cast the returned double to int to get the size
....
```

The most part of the`work`-content is just some junk, I guess you could win some insight into the work of the algorithm by looking at the data - but this is implementation dependent.

However, the first entry of `work` will be the recommended size of the work array, this is also the case if you query the recommended size by setting `lwork = -1`.